# Add ojdbc6 into ireport 5.6.0 classpath in mac os x

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've already install ireport v5.6.0 in mac os x this morning. I want to add oracle driver into ireport classpath but i've noticed that there is no option button under Tool. How do i add ojdbc6 into ireport classpath..Please someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm in windows you do this by going to tools->options and selecting the classpath tab and adding the driver. Does this not appear in the mac version?

Comment: i had just found the solution. Its in ireport->preferences menu right side of apple icon . Just not familiar with the mac version